# Replace certain part of a canvas with image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to replace a part of an HTML canvas with an image. The concept is to put a background image on the canvas that has solid colors. Let's say red and now I make the code loop over the pixels of the image and if the pixels are matched with red then it replaces it with a certain image. Everything works fine but certain images looked zoomed in, I think there's an issue with the drawImage function that I am using.

The code:

```
// Create a canvas element
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id", `canvas${canvasn}`);
        
        // document.body
        var main_room = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');
        main_room.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Load the original image
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = my_image;

        // on load

        document.getElementById('loader').classList.add("myloader");

        img.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

          // Get the image data
          var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
          var data = imgData.data;

          // Put the modified image data back on the canvas
          ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

          if (wall0 != 'none') {

            console.log('CHANGING');
            console.log(wall0);

            var leftwall = new Image();
            leftwall.src = wall0;
            
            leftwall.onload = function() {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
                if (data[i] > 217 && data[i] <= 225 && data[i + 1] > 167 && data[i + 1] < 173 && data[i + 2] > 165 && data[i + 2] < 175) {
                  // Calculate the x and y position of the pixel
                  var x = (i / 4) % img.width;
                  var y = Math.floor((i / 4) / img.width);

                  // Scale the replacement image to match the size of the original image pixel
                  var scaledWidth = 0.5;
                  var scaledHeight = 1;
                  ctx.drawImage(leftwall, x, y, 1, 10, x, y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
                }
              }
            };

          }


        };
```

This code is hosted and running on "[smamarble.com/room1](https://smamarble.com/room1)", feel free to try it. The concept is to select a wall and then select a panel (marble [image]) from the right side to display it on the wall, but again like I mentioned some images work (Kinda) and some look zoomed in.

Answer (score -1):

Your website doesn’t work for me in the latest Firefox or my beloved custom Chromium browser.

I’m also getting crashes but I’m not surprised... if you’re calling **ctx.drawImage()** literally THOUSANDS of times what else can one expect?

Your approach is absolutely INSANE!

Instead, you should load the marble tile in a **separate canvas** for speed, like this:

```
function Load_Marble_Tile(MarblePath){

// The existing canvas, mine has the ID of just "C".

var Cx=C.getContext('2d'); Cx.imageSmoothingEnabled=true; Cx.imageSmoothingQuality='high';

var Data1=Cx.getImageData(0,0,C.width,C.height), D1=Data1.data, L=D1.length;


// The second canvas in which to load each marble tile

var V=document.createElement('canvas'), Vx=V.getContext('2d');

Vx.imageSmoothingEnabled=true; Vx.imageSmoothingQuality='high';


var I=new Image(); I.crossOrigin='anonymous'; I.src=MarblePath;

I.onload=function(){

 V.width=this.naturalWidth; V.height=this.naturalHeight;

 Vx.drawImage(this,0,0,V.width,V.height);

 var Data2=Vx.getImageData(0,0,V.width,V.height), D2=Data2.data, n=0;


 for(var i=0; i<L; i+=4){

  if((D1[i]>217) && (D1[i]<=225) && (D1[i+1]>167) && (D1[i+1]<173) && (D1[i+2]>165) && (D1[i+2]<175)){ 

    D1[i+0]=D2[n+0]; D1[i+1]=D2[n+1]; D1[i+2]=D2[n+2]; D1[i+3]=D2[n+3]; n+=4;

  }

 if(i==(L-4)){Cx.putImageData(Data1,0,0);}}};

}
```

NB: The function can be made smarter by passing R, G and B as function parameters, and then in the loop…

```
if(
 (D1[i]>R-16) && (D1[i]<=R+16) && 
 (D1[i+1]>G-16) && (D1[i+1]<G+16) && 
 (D1[i+2]>B-16) && (D1[i+2]<B+16)){

}
```

Comment: Okay, so it creates a new canvas like expected but instead of only replacing the pixel values R, G, and B, the canvas is entirely filled by the marble tile (image) and yeah passing the R, G, and B values to the function is better as there's more than one color in the main canvas. I also have svg dpath for the colored areas, so my other plan was to create another canvas over the original one and replace just that area with the image.

Comment: Also, please take note how I use the variable “L”, it’s very important for speed and determining the exact moment to load the now modified data. Good luck.